# Java save data from LinkedList to a file

Tags: java, file, object, file-io, stream

Ok, im currently developing a stock control system, and i have it working, but i want to add a feature so it can save the linked list to a file and have a method to do this called saveData() then ill have another method called loadData() that takes in a file name as a parameter.

The methods that will be created must be implemented using object streams.

What does this mean?

Comment: take a look at [serialization](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaSerialization/article.html)

Comment: Which part exactly are you struggling to understand?

Comment: You should probably read at first about java serialization and `Serializable` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` to write to and read from the file.

Serialize the Objects to be saved in file, write to file using `writeObject()` and read using `readObject()`.

Comment: ok thanks, ill have a read on this today on here and big java book. Cheers, I was not sure on the object streams part? that was all